# plotly соотношение пропорции фигуры при увеличении

Tags: python, plotly

Рисую эллипс так, чтобы он выглядел как круг. Но при увеличении/уменьшении он теряет свои пропорции. Как сделать так чтобы увеличивалась только область прямоугольника с определенным соотношением сторон?
Для решения пытался использовать scaleratio и scaleanchor, но вышла проблема что пределы по оси x смещаются и не могут быть настроены при помощи range.

```
import copy

from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

def plot_pie_instead_of_a_marker(fig, x_points, y_points, pie_data, colors, sign, title, unit='',
                                 text=None, norm_param=1, max_r=None, radius_by_par=None):
    def degree2rad(degrees):
        return degrees * np.pi / 180

    def disk_part(center, radius, start_angle, end_angle,  x_max, y_max, n_points=50):
        t = np.linspace(degree2rad(start_angle), degree2rad(end_angle), n_points)
        x = center[0] + radius * x_max * np.cos(t)
        y = center[1] + radius * y_max * np.sin(t)
        return np.append(x, (center[0], x[0])), np.append(y, (center[1], y[0]))

    def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
        return np.sqrt((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2)

    data = [[pie[i] for pie in pie_data] for i in range(0, len(x_points))]
    q_liquid_max = max(pie_data[0] + pie_data[1])

    min_dist = 1e6
    x_max = max(x_points)
    y_max = max(y_points)

    for i in range(0, x_points.size):
        x_dist_zero = distance(x_points[i] / x_max, y_points[i] / y_max, -0.1, y_points[i] / y_max)
        if x_dist_zero < min_dist:
            min_dist = x_dist_zero
        y_dist_zero = distance(x_points[i] / x_max, y_points[i] / y_max, x_points[i] / x_max, -0.1)
        if y_dist_zero < min_dist:
            min_dist = y_dist_zero
        for j in range(i + 1, y_points.size):
            total_dist = distance(x_points[i] / x_max, y_points[i] / y_max, x_points[j] / x_max, y_points[j] / y_max)
            if total_dist < min_dist:
                min_dist = total_dist

    max_r = min_dist * .5
    max_r_liq = max_r
    min_y, max_y = 1e3, 1
    max_x = 0
    min_x = 1e3

    if max_r is None:
        # r = min(min(abs(np.diff(x))), min(abs(np.diff(y)))) * .4  # вычисление радиуса круговой диаграммы
        max_r = 0.05
    if radius_by_par is None:
        radius = np.full(len(x_points), max_r)
    else:
        radius = [max_r * i + 0.02 for i in radius_by_par / max(radius_by_par)]
    sign_catalog = []

    if text is not None:
        sign = f'ID' + ': {0}<br>' + sign
        for title_name in title:
            s = copy.deepcopy(sign)
            s = s + f'<br>{title_name}' + ': {3} ' + unit
            sign_catalog.append(s)
    for x, y, (a, b), id in zip(x_points, y_points, data, text):
        r = (a + b) / q_liquid_max * max_r
        ratio = a / (a + b)
        for start_angle, end_angle, color, sign in zip(
                (0, 360 * ratio), (360 * ratio, 359.9), colors, sign_catalog
        ):
            if start_angle == 0:
                name = sign.format(id, x, y, round(a * norm_param, 0))
            else:
                name = sign.format(id, x, y, round(b * norm_param, 0))
            x_disk, y_disk = disk_part([x, y], r, start_angle, end_angle, x_max, y_max +40)
            max_y = max(max(y_disk), max_y)
            max_x = max(max(x_disk), max_x)
            min_y = min(min(y_disk), min_y)
            min_x = min(min(x_disk), min_x)
            max_r_liq = max(r, max_r_liq)
            fig.add_trace(
                go.Scatter(
                    x=x_disk,
                    y=y_disk,
                    mode='lines',
                    fill="toself",
                    fillcolor=color,
                    line={"color": color},
                    name=name,
                    showlegend=False,
                    hoverinfo='text',
                    hovertext=name,
                    hoverlabel=dict(bgcolor="white", font_color="black")
                )
            )
    fig.update_layout(
        xaxis=dict(
            range=[0, max_x]
        ),
        yaxis=dict(
            range=[min_y, max_y]
        ),
    )

pie_1 = np.array([27.46, 8.95325436, 19.61, 10.25])
pie_2 = np.array([6.68, 0.21357491, 5.02, 0.18])
x = np.array([0.82639155, 0.19306054, 0.3007267,  0.81508946])
y = np.array([94.9698491, 147.00000000000003, 69.3, 57.6])
text = np.array(['1', '2', '3', '4'])
fig = make_subplots()
plot_pie_instead_of_a_marker(
    fig,
    x[y > 0],
    y[y > 0],
    pie_data=[
        pie_1[y > 0],
        pie_2[y > 0]
    ],
    colors=['green', 'deepskyblue'],
    sign='x1: {1: .2f}<br>y: {2:.2f} атм',
    title=['a', 'b'],
    unit='some_unit',
    text=text[y > 0],
    norm_param=1,
)


# Set the y-axis ranges and ratios
fig.update_layout(
    yaxis=dict(
        title='y1',
        # scaleratio=fig.layout.xaxis.range[1] / fig.layout.yaxis.range[1],
        # scaleanchor='x'
    ),
    xaxis=dict(
        range=fig.layout.xaxis.range,
        # title='x',
        scaleratio=fig.layout.yaxis.range[1] / fig.layout.xaxis.range[1],
        scaleanchor='y',
    )
)

fig.show()
```

Comment: надо бы привести минимальный код для воспроизведения проблемы, а не все вот эту вот простыню, с сути вопроса не имеющую отношения.